# How to invert this function?

Tags: functions, closed-form, inverse-function, transcendental-equations, transcendental-functions

I need to invert this function:

$$
y=\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(x-1)}+1
$$

The domain is real (for x>1 and x!=2)

Why can't we just divide it like this:
$$
y=ln(x-(x-1))+1
$$
and then it's:
$$
y=ln(1)+1
$$
so it seems wrong.
Where did I make the mistake?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: where did you come across this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, $\dfrac{\ln a}{\ln b}\ne \ln(a-b)$.

**Remarks:**  $1.$ The false simplification was probably motivated by $\ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)=\ln a-\ln b$, which is true for positive $a$ and $b$.

$2.$ (added) If $x\ne 1$, then the equation can be manipulated to $y\ln(x-1)=\ln x+\ln(x-1)$. We recognize $y\ln(x-1)$ as the logarithm of $(x-1)^y$. So we can rewrite our equation as $(x-1)^y=x(x-1)$, which, since $x\ne 1$, can be simplified to $(x-1)^{y-1}=x$. It is likely that the solution can be written in terms of the [Lambert $W$-function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) A solution in terms of elementary functions seems highly unlikely.

Comment: yes, exactly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is wrong, because you can use the property of ln, only when $ln \left ( \frac{a}{b} \right )=ln(a) - ln(b)$
Try to use the inverse of ln, we know from lections that it is the exponential function e.

Answer (score 0):

This function is a really interesting one, I think. I've been looking at a similar one for a while: $y=\frac{\ln (x+1)}{\ln x}$. In fact, I think that my function is just yours but slid up one unit on both axes. I'm fairly sure that the inverses of your function can't be expressed with a finite number of elementary functions, or even a finite number of a wide variety of functions like the Lambert W function or the error function. I wasn't aware of your question, but I [asked about my version of the function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257455/inverse-function-of-y-frac-lnx1-ln-x), and it got a bit more attention than this did. Maybe you can get something out of the answers that I got.

Comment: It is trivial to show that your function is the same as the OPs under the translation $x \mapsto x+1$, $y\mapsto y-1$. Of course, terms and conditions apply at points of discontinuity, etc.

Answer (score 0):

$$y=\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(x-1)}+1$$

For real $a,b$, there is the rule $\ln(a\cdot b)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$, not your simplification.

Your function is an [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). It's a binary algebraic function of two algebraically independent monomials. It doesn't have an elementary inverse therefore.

$$y-1=\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(x-1)}$$

$$1=\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(x-1)(y-1)}$$

$$\ln(x-1)=\frac{\ln(x)}{(y-1)}$$

$$x-1=e^{\frac{\ln(x)}{(y-1)}}$$

Lambert W cannot be applied here.

$$x-1=x^{\frac{1}{y-1}}$$

For rational $y\neq 1,2$, this equation is related to an algebraic equation and we can use the known solution formulas and methods for algebraic equations.
For rational $y\neq 1,2$, the equation is related to a [trinomial equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial).
For real or complex $y\neq 1,2$, the equation is in a form similar to a trinomial equation. A closed-form solution can be obtained using confluent [Fox-Wright Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function) $\ _1\Psi_1$ therefore.
$\ $

[Szabó, P. G.: On the roots of the trinomial equation. Centr. Eur. J. Operat. Res. 18 (2010) (1) 97-104](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225959964_On_the_roots_of_the_trinomial_equation)

[Belkić, D.: All the trinomial roots, their powers and logarithms from the Lambert series, Bell polynomials and Fox–Wright function: illustration for genome multiplicity in survival of irradiated cells. J. Math. Chem. 57 (2019) 59-106](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10910-018-0985-3)