# Approximate inverse of $k=\frac{\log (1-t)}{\log (t)}$

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, transcendental-equations

Trying to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4554697/general-method-for-solving-ax-bx-cx/4558814#4558814) where we look for the solution of
$$\large\color{red}{t^k+t=1} \qquad \qquad \text{with} \qquad \color{red}{0<k<1}$$ which is more or less the function Lambert considered.

In my update, I rewrote it as
$$\large\color{blue}{k=\frac{\log (1-t)}{\log (t)}}$$

The plot of $t$ as a function $k$ is not very nice but my surprise came from the plot of $t$ as a function of $\log(k)$ which is extremely close to a logistic function.
[image]

[image]

I came very quickly to the approximate result
$$\large\color{blue}{t\sim\frac 1 {1+k^{-\log_2 (\phi )}}}$$ ($\phi$ being the golden ratio). This reproduces exactly the value of $t$ for $k=\frac 12$; at this point, the slope is in a relative error of $0.3$%.

This surprising value  being used as the $t_0$ of Newton method, some results

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
k & t_0 & t_1 & \text{solution} \\
 0.05 & 0.11107938 & 0.10607326 &  0.10610459 \\
 0.10 & 0.16818422 & 0.16491137 &  0.16492096 \\
 0.15 & 0.21130781 & 0.20917626 &  0.20917956 \\
 0.20 & 0.24650516 & 0.24512115 &  0.24512233 \\
 0.25 & 0.27639320 & 0.27550762 &  0.27550804 \\
 0.30 & 0.30240988 & 0.30186067 &  0.30186067 \\
 0.35 & 0.32545141 & 0.32513010 &  0.32513010 \\
 0.40 & 0.34612246 & 0.34595481 &  0.34595481 \\
 0.45 & 0.36485403 & 0.36478837 &  0.36478837 \\
 0.50 & 0.38196601 & 0.38196601 &  0.38196601 \\
 0.55 & 0.39770340 & 0.39774335 &  0.39774335 \\
 0.60 & 0.41225852 & 0.41232020 &  0.41232020 \\
 0.65 & 0.42578544 & 0.42585602 &  0.42585602 \\
 0.70 & 0.43840971 & 0.43848026 &  0.43848026 \\
 0.75 & 0.45023507 & 0.45029952 &  0.45029952 \\
 0.80 & 0.46134837 & 0.46140274 &  0.46140274 \\
 0.85 & 0.47182302 & 0.47186491 &  0.47186491 \\
 0.90 & 0.48172173 & 0.48174985 &  0.48174985 \\
 0.95 & 0.49109845 & 0.49111241 &  0.49111241 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

To give an idea, I considered as a measure
$$\Phi_n=\int_0^1 \Bigg[k-\frac{\log (1-t_n)}{\log (t_n)}\Bigg]^2\,dk$$
$$\Phi_0=2.157 \times 10^{-6}\qquad \Phi_1=6.282 \times 10^{-11}\qquad \Phi_2=4.007 \times 10^{-18}$$

**Edit**

After @Jam's answer, I minimized
$$\Psi(a)=\int_0^1 \Bigg[k-\frac{\log \left(1+k^a\right)}{\log \left(1+k^{-a}\right)} \Bigg]^2\,dk$$ The result is
$$a_{\text{min}}=0.69603517 \quad \implies \quad \Psi(a_{\text{min}})=1.668 \times 10^{-6}$$

For this number, the $ISC$ proposes the amazing
$$a_{\text{min}}\sim  \frac{\sqrt[2]{2}\,\, \sqrt[3]{3}-9}{10} $$

**Could this be even partly justified ?**

Comment: What is $\phi$?

Comment: Oddly, there was a question (10 years ago) https://math.stackexchange.com/q/264566/305862 about the inverse function of $\log(\color{red}{t-1})/\log(t)$ [which hasn't at all the same domain ($(1,+\infty)$ instead of $(0,1)$]

Comment: @Gary $\phi$ = golden ratio.

Comment: @JeanMarie. Could I ask you a favor ? I am unable to produce decent plots. WOuld tou accept to add the two plots I mention in the question ?

Comment: I found that for large $k$, $t \sim 1 - \frac{{W_0 (k)}}{k} \sim 1 - \frac{{\log k}}{k} + \frac{{\log \log k }}{k} - \frac{{\log \log k}}{{k\log k}}$. This of course does not answer your question.

Comment: @Gary. As I wrote, this is almost the equation Lambert worked before $W$

Comment: Yes, of course. I just did on the same figure the two plots (with GeoGebra) and inserted it in your question. Say if it's OK.

Comment: I found that if $t = \frac{1}{{1 + k^{ - \alpha (k)} }}$ then $\log 2 < \alpha (k) < 1$ for $0<k<1$, and $$
\alpha (k) \sim \frac{{W_0(1/k )}}{{ \log (1/k)}} \sim 1 + \frac{{\log ( - \log k)}}{{\log (k)}} + \frac{{\log ( - \log k)}}{{\log ^2 (k)}}
$$ as $k\to 0^+$.

Comment: @JeanMarie. Thanks but the first plot has to be $t=f(k)$ and the second $t=g(\log(k))$.

Comment: @Gary. This is great !

Comment: In this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3485742/305862) it is also proposed the very close approximation $y=\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)^{3/2}$

Comment: Sorry, Claude, there must exist a misunderstanding. Set apart the name of the variables (I am constraint to use x and y with GeoGebra) 1) The plots I have inserted are there for "proving" that indeed the two curves are almost perfectly symmetrical with respect to the $y=x$ axis. 2) Do you want to produce another figure as a function of $\log k$ but for which purpose ?

Comment: @JeanMarie. I am sorry to disturb. The only thing I would like to show (two different plots would be required) is how ugly is $t$ as a function of $k$ and how nice is $t$ as a function of $\log(k)$ without any consideration of any approximation. You can use part of the table since there are the values of $k$ and the value of $t$ (the solution).

Comment: @JeanMarie The plot in question is given implicitly by $x=\log(\log(1-y)/\log y)$.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Ok, let us attempt a convergent result. ( ; Maybe the first attempt will not be what you desire ; please say me)

Comment: @Gary Thanks !...

Comment: Just added a graphic : is it the good one ? Feel free to erase it if it is not convenient, and correct me...

Comment: Maybe, you would have liked me to plot $y=\frac{1}{1+e^{-a \ln(x)}}$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie. Thank you so much ! I did not "see" it.

Comment: Maybe $\log_t(1-t)=\lim\limits_{a\to0}\frac{(1-t)^a-1}{t^a-1}$ is useful?

Comment: Can confluent Fox-Wright Function $\ _1\Psi_1$ help here, like in my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4554697/general-method-for-solving-ax-bx-cx/4558814#4558814 ?

Comment: @IV_. Could you eleborate ? I am still working this problem and I am totally stuck. Thanks and cheers :-)

Comment: Comment addendum: You could solve $(1-t)^a-k(t^a-1)-1=0$ with a better solution as $a\to 0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not have much experience with these curves. I tried change of variables. But for me, $x$ and $y$ complicated the equations.

1. If $t^k+t=1$ fits $k^ct+t=1$ then $t^{k-1}$ fits $k^c$. At $(k,t)=(2,\phi^{-1})$ we have $c=-\frac{\ln\phi}{\ln 2}$.
2. By implicit differentiation, $\frac{dt}{dk}=-\frac{t^k\ln t}{kt^{k-1}+1}$ fits $\frac{dt}{dk}=-\frac{ck^{c-1}}{(1+k^c)^2}$. Then, I somehow found that $c$ fits $\frac{k\ln t}{k(1-t)+t}$ and at $(k,t)=(2,\phi^{-1})$, we have
   $$c=-\frac{2\phi^2\ln\phi}{\phi +2}\approx -0.696416$$

Comment: This is more than interesting ! It does not match the function value and first derivative at $k=\frac 12$ but it looks to be a good compromise. I stop everything and I work that. I shall let you know. Thansk & cheers & (+1). :-)

Comment: This is much better. It gives $\Phi_0=1.690 \times 10^{-6}$ instead of $\Phi_0=2.157 \times 10^{-6}$

Answer (score 7):

From $t^k+t=1$, we indeed have, as you derived, $\displaystyle k=\frac{\ln\left(1-t\right)}{\ln t}$. And you claim that the graph of $t$ against $\ln k$ appears to be approximately a logistic function in $\ln k$, given by $\displaystyle t=\frac{1}{1+e^{-a\ln k}}=\frac1{1+k^{-a}}$ for some constant $a\approx 0.693$. However, instead of your $a=\log_{2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}\right)=0.694$, I find $a=\ln 2=0.693$.

We justify the claim as follows, by proving, in particular, that the implicit function $\displaystyle e^{x}=\frac{\ln\left(1-y\right)}{\ln y}$, in which $x$ corresponds to $\ln k$ and $y$ to $t$, has a derivative that is approximately quadratic in $y$, which implies the desired logistic approximation.

Through implicit differentiation and the chain and quotient rules, we have $\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{-1}{u\left(1-y\right)+u\left(y\right)}$, where $u(x)=1/({x\ln x})$. Then, $ \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ is, with respect to $y$, concave down (inverse U-shaped) and symmetric about $x=0.5$, with zeros at $x=0$ and $1$ and a maximum of $\ln (2) / 4$. If we then fit a quadratic in $y$ to $ \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ with roots at $0,1$ also and an identical maximum, it will be exactly equal to $ \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ at $0$, $0.5$, and $1$, and, by continuity, have an error that is concave and bounded (and, in principle, small) on each of the two intervals between those values. Numerically, we indeed find that the absolute error is at most $4.82\times10^{-3}$.

This gives the approximation $ \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\approx \ln 2\, y (1-y)$, which is a differential equation with the logistic function $\displaystyle y=\frac{1}{1+C\,2^{-x}}$ as its solution, where we see from the initial value $y(0)=0.5$ that $C=1$. And therefore, $\displaystyle t\approx \frac1{1+k^{-\ln 2}}$.

Comment: Very interesting ! You make it even simpler. With this value $\Phi_0=2.938\times 10^{-6}$,  $\Phi_1=7.731\times 10^{-11}$,  $\Phi_2=4.907\times 10^{-18}$. Thanks & cheers & $(+1).

Comment: Just copying my comment above which is related to your answer: I found that if $t = \frac{1}{{1 + k^{ - \alpha (k)} }}$ then $\log 2<\alpha(k)<1$ for $0<k<1$, and
$$\alpha (k) \sim \frac{{W_0(1/k )}}{{ \log (1/k)}} \sim 1 + \frac{{\log ( - \log k)}}{{\log (k)}} + \frac{{\log ( - \log k)}}{{\log ^2 (k)}} \sim 1$$
as $k\to 0^+$.

Comment: Look at my edit

Answer (score 0):

There is an analytical solution using a new special function called

$W_q(z)$ or Lambert-Tsallis function. This function is defined as a solution of $ X\cdot (1 + (1-q)\cdot X)^\frac{1}{1-q} = z$.

For sake of simplicity I like to call it $W_{"r"}(z)$ Defined as solution of the polynomy

$ X\cdot \bigg(1 + \frac{X}{r}\bigg)^r = z$, and $r=\frac{1}{1-q}$

So, only for a detail of nomenclature, after a few manipulation one can analitically find

$ t = \bigg(\frac{W_{"r"}(r)}{r}\bigg) ^\frac{1}{r\cdot k}$    (1)

and $r=\frac{1-k}{k}$

When $k=0.5$ one has $r=1$. However, $W_{"1"}(1)=\phi=0.618033248239453$ or $-1.618034622558085$. Only the positive value is considered. Thus, substituting, one would take

$ t = \bigg(\frac{\phi}{1}\bigg) ^2 = 0.381965095929409$ that corresponds to the values found at table. The analytical results using $W_q(z)$ is show in the following tables for $t$ using the same previously data

| t | k |
| --- | --- |
| 0.106105111882033 | 0.05 |
| 0.164920356980167 | 0.10 |
| 0.209179436174934 | 0.15 |
| 0.245122552355033 | 0.20 |
| 0.275507532000750 | 0.25 |
| 0.301861318986113 | 0.30 |
| 0.325130035349145 | 0.35 |
| 0.345954813133744 | 0.40 |
| 0.364788831763960 | 0.45 |
| 0.381966555040667 | 0.50 |
| 0.397742867431469 | 0.55 |
| 0.412320670850846 | 0.60 |
| 0.425855828574802 | 0.65 |
| 0.438480356363474 | 0.70 |
| 0.450299821476583 | 0.75 |
| 0.461403048715524 | 0.80 |
| 0.471864671170827 | 0.85 |
| 0.481750909739635 | 0.90 |
| 0.491111506254522 | 0.95 |