# Solve for $x$ in $x^y - x = 1$.

Tags: exponential-function, problem-solving, inverse-function

Consider the equation $x^y - x = 1.$ I'd like to find a closed form expression for $x$ in terms of $y$. It's pretty easy to solve for $y$ in terms of $x$:

$y = \dfrac{\ln(x+1)}{\ln(x)}\tag*{}$

Obviously there are domain restrictions here: $x>0, x\ne 1$. However, I have no idea how to find the inverse function. A quick graph of the equation suggests that $x$ is indeed a function of $y,$ defined for all $y \notin (0, 1]$:

[[image: Plot of <span class=]$x^y - x = 1$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sme60.png)

Comment: @Doug: How do you get that?

Comment: @Dan, My bad ... I was just being dumb

Comment: Having an inverse does not imply having a close form of an inverse.

Comment: FWIW, I tried Wolfram Alpha, but just got "Standard computation time exceeded..."

Comment: Looks like duplicate of [How to solve $x^y=ax−b$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4463894/746312) with $a=1$ and $b=-1$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve $x^y = ax-b$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4463894/how-to-solve-xy-ax-b)

Comment: This question has an answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257455/inverse-function-of-y-frac-lnx1-ln-x/4494271#4494271.