# Inverse function of elementary function

Tags: calculus

Is the statement true or false : inverse function of elementary function is also elementary

I think it would not be true, but i can’t find any counterexample(non-elementary inverse of elementary function)

Is there any counterexample of this?

Comment: There are some like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257455/inverse-function-of-y-frac-lnx1-ln-x). Multiplying/adding a linear and nonlinear function, like $\sin(x),e^x$, also very likely makes the inverse nonelementary

Comment: If $~f(x) = Ax^5 + Bx^4 + Cx^3 + Dx^2 + E,~$ then what is the inverse function to $~f(x)~?$

Comment: The only possible exception I could think of is inverse ("arc") trig ratios.  Calculating sine as a function is simple, but I'm not sure how to calculate the arcsine as a function, I just "work it backwards".